# Translation operator in polar coordinates

Tags: functional-analysis

Translation operator $P_\alpha$ in Cartesian coordinates act on wave function as

$P_\alpha\psi(x,y)=\psi(x+a\cos\alpha,y+a\sin\alpha)$

The operator is unitary since

$\int{\psi^*(x+a\cos\alpha,y+a\sin\alpha)\psi(x+a\cos\theta,y+a\sin\alpha)} dxdy=\int{\psi^*(x,y)\psi(x,y)} dxdy$

where in the first integral substitution

$x'=x+a\cos\alpha$,

$ y'=y+a\sin\alpha$

But in polar coordinates we have

$P_\alpha\psi(x,y)=\psi(r+a,\theta)$

so

$\int{r drd\theta\psi^*(r+a,\theta)\psi(r+a,\theta)}\neq \int{r drd\theta\psi^*(r,\theta)\psi(r,\theta)}$.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Subtracting a constant from the x coordinate and a possibly different (although you have used 'a' in both cases) constant from the y coordinate translates points in the plane. Subtracting a constant from the r coordinate does not. Draw some points and try both operations, to see what I mean.

Comment: Supose we have a the point $x=1$ and $y=2$ this correspond to the point $r=\sqrt{5} in polar coordinates.  The translated point $x'=2, y'=4$ correspond to

Comment: You have translated the point by the vector (1,2). The result is the same as if you had scaled the point by the factor 2, but this is not the case for all points. For instance, translating the point (0,1) by the vector (1,2) gives the point (1,3), while scaling the point (0,1) by the factor 2 gives the point (0,2). PS Don't forget the theta coordinate, in polar coordinates.

Comment: I am only interested  in scaling. Since scaling is unitary in Cartesian coordinates it should be unitary in polar

Comment: I see that you have edited your question, to replace "translation" by "scaling". However, in your first equation, the subtraction of a from x and b from y represents a translation, not a scaling. In your second equation, subtraction of a from r represents neither a translation, nor a scaling. Scaling is represented in polar coordinates by *multiplying* r by a constant.

Comment: So what adding a constant to the radial coordinates  does not mean translate in radial direction?

Comment: Try it for yourself. Draw a simple picture, like a child's drawing of a house or something. Draw the origin somewhere in the middle of your picture. In a different colour, draw the picture that results from adding a constant to the radius of every point. In yet another colour, draw the result of multiplying the radius of every point by a constant.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84481/discussion-between-amilton-moreira-and-simon).

Answer (score 1):

Your $\theta$ is a function of $x$ and $y$. It is $\arctan(y/x)$ (for $x$ not equal to $0$). The equation with the integrals is only true, if $\theta$ (and $a$) are fixed, that is, not dependent on $x$ and $y$. I think this is the heart of your problem.